# Native VLAN (Cisco term) vs. PVID (IEEE 802.1q Standard), What's the difference?

Tags: networking, vlan, 802.1q

> Still working on updating this but I welcome suggestions, corrections or comments...

> Background: *I saw this question crop up in a couple of posts dealing with VLAN configurations on Home Networking Devices such as the TP-Link TL-SG108E<sup>[2.1](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg108e/)</sup>.  I also didn't see any similar questions while writing this one so I think I'm in the clear with this post (let me know otherwise).  There seemed to be confusion among questioners, commentators, and answer-givers, hence my decision to post this **Q&A** to help set the record straight.*

---

### Question: What is the difference between PVID and Native VLAN?

When configuring a home-networking device such as the [TP-Link: TL-SG108E](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg108e/) you are offered 4 different options for configuring VLANs and they are as follows:

- [MTU VLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63XwN.png)
- [Port Based VLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OpQo.png)
- [802.1Q VLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD2Ck.png)
- [802.1Q PVID Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF3zY.png)

The last list item is the setting that seemed to confuse a number of people because at first glance it looks like the "Native VLAN®" setting you'd find on Cisco IOS® networking devices, and their clones like Linksys© WiFi Routers and Switches.

---

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

First and foremost, the term *Native VLAN* doesn't appear anywhere in the IEEE 802.1Q whitepaper since it is a proprietary name given to a Cisco© feature that enables Cisco Trunk ports to accept untagged port-traffic and to still pass it along their uplink(s) to upstream network-device(s) instead of dropping it. Native VLANs are used on uplink ports that are carrying multiple tagged VLANs and where you want any untagged traffic to get put into a specific VLAN before it reaches an upstream device, or vice-versa where you want ingress traffic coming from the uplinks that is untagged to be tagged before pushing it to the related ports carrying those same VLAN IDs.

PVIDs are port-based VLAN-IDs that allow a device/edge port to receive both tagged and untagged traffic. This is used a lot in scenarios with a PC connected port (untagged PC traffic) and where a VoIP Telephone is connected through the PC and into the same switch-port. In this scenario you would set the phone to tagging on (e.g. VLAN 20), the switch-port PVID to tagged (e.g. VLAN 20) and untagged (e.g. VLAN 1), and the PC net-interface set with no tagging so that it gets plopped into VLAN 1.

You could create a partial-configuration for a "Native VLAN" on an up-link port using PVIDs but the same is usually accomplished by simply setting 802.1Q tagged and untagged ports on the same port.

This [article](https://www.megajason.com/2018/04/30/what-is-pvid/) covers the answer better than I can and so I won't try to explain any further.